# Dependence on msvcr120d.dll Visual Studio 2015 (Intel TBB)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, tbb

In order to get Intel TBB (Thread Building Blocks) to work with visual studio 2015, I tried the following approach (because, by default, the built binaries are only for upto vs2013).

Compile Intel TBB with Visual Studio 2015 -

1. Download source code of Intel TBB from [Here](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download).
2. Extract it,
3. Open the VS2010 Solution `makefile.sln` with path `tbb<version>\build\VS2010`
4. Approve the conversion of project file to use Visual 2015 toolkit
5. Select Debug Configuration and x64 Platform and buid. (note if already done previous build, then re-build (clean and build)).
6. Copy the dll, pdb, lib, exp, def files from `tbb<version>\build\VS2010\intel64\Debug` to `tbb<version>\lib\Debug`.

Create New Empty Visual C++ Project

Make the following changes for the debug, x64 configuration

1. Add additional include directories `tbb<version>\include`
2. Add additional Library Directories `tbb<version>\lib\Debug`
3. Add the following library dependencies

   ```
   tbbmalloc_debug.lib
   tbbmalloc_proxy_debug.lib
   tbb_debug.lib
   ```
4. Select `Debug, x64` configuration and Build. The Build was successful.

The Code used to test this is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>

// #include "..\Headers\MexMem.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::vector<int> A(100, 0);
    std::vector<int> B(100, 0);
    std::vector<int> C(100, 0);

    mt19937_64 RandNoEngine;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> RandNoGenerator;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        A[i] = RandNoGenerator(RandNoEngine);
        B[i] = RandNoGenerator(RandNoEngine);
    }

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, 100), [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> &Range) {
        int beg = Range.begin();
        int end = Range.end();
        for (int i = beg; i < end; ++i) {
            C[i] = A[i] * B[i];
        }
    });
    cout << A[30] << " * " << B[30] << " = " << C[30] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Press F5 to debug, Here I get an Error of **The program can't start because MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.** Next message is related to MSVCR120D.dll. Note that this is occurring after building everything (including the TBB Libraries) using Visual 2015.

**Additional Info**

A quick analysis with Dependancy Walker (depends.exe) gives the following results:

THe dependency of `tbb_debug.lib` is as below

```
- TBB_DEBUG.dll 
   - KERNEL32.DLL
   - MSVCP140D.DLL
   - VCRUNTIME140D.DLL
   - UCRTBASED.DLL
```

However the Dependencies of `tbb_debug.lib` as shown in the Exe (exe of above program) is as below:

```
- TBB_EXPERIMENT.EXE
   - TBB_DEBUG.dll
      ? MSVCP120D.DLL
      ? MSVCR120D.DLL
      - KERNEL32.
```

Why the discrepancy? Is there any way to get more info related to this, and finally, is there a way to correctly compile and debug Intel TBB on Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Have you checked the full path in Depends to the DLL?  This looks like it is loading the wrong TBB_DEBUG.dll.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ah Yes. That indeed seems to be the case. I think this is because I recently upgraded The Visual Studio and something is still forcing Visual Studio to prod into the Composer studio Libs. I will look into what is causing this, see if i can fix it and let you know.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You hit the nail on the head. While working on the previous version, I had included the redistributable library folder of Intel TBB in the Path Environment Variable which causes Visual Studio to bypass the folders I had told it to look into. Please Post Your Comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it is loading the wrong TBB_DEBUG.DLL.  Check the full path to the DLL in Dependency Walker.